# Writing values in a Python dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I'm totally new to python, thus the question.

My input comes in the following manner,

```
Krishna 67 68 69 36 42
```

There are several lines of input with the first string giving the name of a student followed by his marks. I need to create a hash map and add the marks to a list for every student.
Also I need to stop when there is no more input. How can I do this in Python 3. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
grades = {}
#for each input (using some kind of for/while loop to get lines of input)
    #split the string at the spaces into a list of strings
    info = input_str.split()
    #the first string is a name 
    #if using first and last name us " ".join(info[0:2])
    name = info[0]
    #convert each score to an int() using a list comprehension
    scores = [int(score) for score in info[1:]]
    #save the result
    grades[name] = scores
```

Comment: Note that in Python 3, you can directly unpack to the appropriate names: `name, *scores = input_str.split()`, then follow up with a list comp `scores = [int(score) for score in scores]` to fix up the types.